# C++: structs across classes

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have two classes: MazeClass and CreatureClass, that use a struct called "coordinates," how am I able to use the struct across both classes?
I've tried to put the struct in twice and I get:

> MazeClass.h:16:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct coordinate’
>
> CreatureClass.h:11:18: error: previous definition of ‘struct coordinate’

Comment: Let's see the headers especially how the classes and  coordinate are declared

Comment: Are both structures the same?  Most of the answers assume that they are, but you can easily have a naming conflict between two different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the struct in one of the classes in public. Choose the class that is more relevant:

```
class MazeClass
{
public:
    struct coordinate {} ;
} ;
```

Other classes can access this type as `MazeClass::coordinate`. Alternatively you can bring it with a typedef.

```
class CreatureClass
{
public:
    typedef MazeClass::coordinate coordinate ;
} ;
```

Answer (score 7):

You should only define the struct once across your header files. Move `coordinates` into its own header file (with an include guard), then include that header in both of your other headers.

Example `coordinates.h`:

```
#ifndef COORDINATES_H
#define COORDINATES_H

struct coordinates {
    // ...
};

#endif
```

Technically, it's OK to define `coordinates` in two headers (though horrible from a maintainability perspective -- stay [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!). The problems arise when another header or implementation file includes both of those headers (either directly or indirectly) -- then the compiler sees two different `coordinates` struct definitions (it doesn't know they're the same), and complains with the errors you've posted.

Comment: I found this solution to *just work*.  I tried the accepted answer and didn't have any luck.  Thanks, @Cameron!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the definition of `struct coordinate` in a single common location instead of duplicating it.  Maybe create a new `coordinate.h` file?  Don't forget to use include guards.

Answer (score 0):

In algebra this is called "factoring out" the common factors.

Create a "coordinate.h" file.  in it, using include guards, place the definition of your coordinate struct.

Then use `#include "coordinate.h"` in both MazeClass.h and CreatureClass.h.